# Custom Pipeline Directories in C#

Tags: c#, dll, add-in, pipeline

I have created a pipeline for addins using C#. Once compiled all the .dll files used in the pipeline are specified in separate folders i.e. \addinsideadapters\AddInSideAdapters.dll; \addinviews\AddInView.dll etc.

Is there a way to compile and run the .dll files from the root directory instead of the default add-in sub-directories - and possibly rename the files to something else like aisa.dll; aiv.dll etc?

Comment: Yes: type copy /? at the command prompt, followed by ren /?. If you want a way to automate this, you must give us a bit more info.

Comment: thanks for your response - sorry just updated my description was it was confusing. i was looking for a response within the add-in code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy the pipeline assemblies in the root folder. MAF will throw an [AddInSegmentDirectoryNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.hosting.addinsegmentdirectorynotfoundexception.aspx) when calling methods [AddInStore.Rebuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.hosting.addinstore.rebuild.aspx) or [AddInStore.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470575.aspx).

What you can do is rename the assemblies to any name you wish. You can also deploy the actual add-ins in a folder of your choice. You then specify the folder containing subfolders with the add-in assemblies when calling [AddInStore.FindAddIns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.hosting.addinstore.findaddins.aspx) or [AddInStore.FindAddIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.hosting.addinstore.findaddin.aspx).

Hope this helps.